# Issue with converting string to a datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I've a datetime (int64) column in my pandas dataframe.
I'm trying to convert its value of 201903250428 to a datetime value.

The value i have for the datetime (int64) column is only till minute level with 24 hours format.

I tried various methods like striptime, to_datetime methods but no luck.

```
pd.datetime.strptime('201903250428','%y%m%d%H%M')
```

I get this error when i use the above code.

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0428
```

I wanted this value to be converted to like '25-03-2019 04:28:00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower-case `y` means two-digit years only, so this is trying to parse "20" as the year, 1 as the month, 9 the day, and 03:25 as the time, leaving "0428" unconverted.

You need to use `%Y` which will work fine:

```
pd.datetime.strptime('201903250428','%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

http://strftime.org/ is a handy reference for time formatting/parsing parameters.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your answer helped me for this calculation. pd.to_datetime('201903250428',format='%Y%m%d%H%M',errors='coerce')